# Bitmasks vs bloom filters

Tags: algorithm, search, optimization, bitmask, bloom-filter

I am looking to pre-filter search results either using a bloom filter or a bitmask. To give a concrete example:

```
id,product,description
1,"coke", "A popular soft drink since 1900"
2,"pepsi", "A popular soda, similar to coke"
3,"soda", "A word to describe various soft drinks"
```

And if the user searched for the word "coke" we would match on `product="coke"` for row1 and `description(has word)="coke"`.

We have memory constraints so cannot index too many items, but I was thinking of implementing a bitmask based upon the first letter that each row contains. In that way, we can see that the `c` are included in rows 1 and 2, but not in row 3, so we wouldn't include that in our search at all.

If we took the first three rows, the "word-starts-with" mask would look like (for the first 3 letters of the alphabet) --

```
a  b  c  d
1  0  1  1 (row 1 -- coke)  -- has c? Y
1  0  1  0 (row 2 -- pepsi) -- has c? Y
1  0  0  1 (row 3 -- soda)  -- has c? NO -- SKIP
```

My question then is two-fold:

- For a scenario such as the above, would there be any advantage is using a bloom filter over a bitmask? Why or why not? (I'm not too familiar with bloom filters and have never used one myself).
- Does the above one-letter bitmask seem like it would be useful, or does it seem like it wouldn't solve anything really (for example, every row could have `a=1`) at one-character only?
- Are there suggested ways to work around common letters/words. For example, "a/an", "the", etc. seem like they would occur in almost all columns with natural text.

---

A few more details about the search requirements:

- The maximum data size would be 1GB. This would translate to anywhere between 1M-10M rows depending on the size of the rows.
- There is very, very little additional room available, so something like a traditional index would be out of the question. For reference, let's suppose there is 10% headroom on any data set to store ancillary information, such as a bitmask/filter/index/etc.
- Two example queries would be `description like "%drink%"` (full inner search) or `description REGEXP '^|\sdrink'` ("edge search", search at the start of any word).

Comment: Bloom Filters are cool, and I would love to share the implementation details of what we did for a product feature once. But here's the primary question - what are your memory constraints, how many entries will you actually have, and the avg size of each product/description string?  You'll also need to implement a word-breaker algorithm...

Comment: @selbie cool -- the data size could be around 800MB / a few million rows, and we don't have much headroom to store additional data structures (I would say 10% headroom). Currently our word-break is on space/tab for a few separate reasons (a person could enter in a date with dashes/slashes, and a few other oddities).

Comment: your bitmask is a Bloom filter with a really bad hash function

Comment: @MattTimmermans why would a hash function be needed in this case though (or would it not?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bitmasks are simple Bloom filters: Assuming you care about 26 possible characters, that is a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) with `m = 26 * rowCount`, `k = 1`, and the following hash function: `hash(firstLetter, rowId) = (firstLetter * rowCount + rowId)`. This is simple to implement, but likely not very efficient, as some letters appear very often (e.g. the character 'e'). Your bitmask needs about 4 bytes per row, which might be OK. For each row, you do a Bloom filter lookup.

It is likely better to use a more sophisticated Bloom filter. How it looks like exactly depends on the data you have. Assuming you use `m = 26 * rowCount`, `k = 1`, and `hash(firstLetter, secondLetter, rowId) = ((11 * firstLetter + 113 * secondLetter) modulo 26) * rowCount + rowId)`. That way, it uses the same space, but bits are more evenly distributed. For frequent letters, that speeds up search a lot, at the cost of slightly slower search for less frequent letters.

Even better might be to combine multiple rows, let's say combine 8 rows each (rows 0..7, 8..15,...), and then set all the bits in the Bloom filter that are needed. That way, you can reduce the number of lookups greatly.

If your queries can be of the form `like "%drink%"`, then a filter that only looks at the first characters is not useful: you still have to do a full scan. Instead, you could have a Bloom filter that combines (say) 8 rows, and sets all the bits of each character pair. That is, `['dr', 'ri', 'in', 'nk']`, and use `m = 26 * rowCount / 8`, `k = 1`, and `hash(firstLetter, secondLetter, rowGroup) = ((11 * firstLetter + 113 * secondLetter) modulo 26) * rowCount / 8 + rowGroup), with`rowGroup = rowId / 8`. So you basically check whether a character pair appears in a certain row group. That way, you can use the Bloom filter even for "like" conditions and regular expressions.

Comment: thanks so much for this reply. I've added some additional details to the question about the data size and number of rows.

Comment: additionally, could you please clarify why 64 characters would be needed? I was thinking with letters (a-z) it would be 26, when lowercased and could fit in a 4 byte bitmask.

Comment: Sure, I will update my answer. See, it would be good to get more info on what you plan / need to do.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot tolerate false positives, you must not use bloom filter as it is a probabilistic data structure.

For the bitmask approach, apparently, is not time efficient and the approach would be difficult to scale later. As you talk about data size of around 800 MB, you are entering the paradigm of [Search or Information Retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval). The question now doesn't remain confined to 'Bitmasks vs Bloom Filters' Just have a read at the indexing related concepts in [Search Engine Indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing#Indexing), they might help you.

To work around with the common words, please read what [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) are and how to remove them. To go to a bit more next level, if you don't need to find the exact word, read about [Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and [Lemmatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation).

The question is quite broad so I just gave a few pointers to read. Hope you find them useful.

Comment: How would having a bitmask (on one letter) not be space efficient, I don't get that? A 32 bit mask would be storing one additional integer per row?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say time efficient. Edited the answer.

Comment: When you say "it's not time efficient", could you please clarify what you mean? It doesn't get any faster (that I'm aware of?) in doing bitwise operations, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It will not be efficient in cases where the first or many initial characters are same for a lengthy string.